# error showing when i try to add tab to my android application

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin

i keep getting this error whn i compile the code Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Widget.TabHost.NewTabSpec(string)'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace EmployeeDirectory.Android
{
    [Activity (Label = "TabsLayoutActivity" , MainLauncher = true, Icon="@drawable/ic_launcher")]           
    public class TabsLayoutActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.TabsLayout);
            CreateTab(typeof(CalendarActivity), "Calendar", "Calendar",      Resource.Drawable.Calendar);
            CreateTab(typeof(HospitalActivity), "Nearest Hospital", "Nearest Hospital", Resource.Drawable.Hospital);
            CreateTab(typeof(MapActivity), "Maps and Location", "Maps and Location", Resource.Drawable.Maps);
            CreateTab(typeof(EverciseActivity), "Exercises", "Exercises", Resource.Drawable.Exercises);
            CreateTab(typeof(DietActivity), "Diet", "Diet", Resource.Drawable.Diet);
            // Create your application here
        }
        private void CreateTab(Type activityType, string tag, string label, int drawableId )
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            var spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);
            var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId);
            spec.SetIndicator(label, drawableIcon);
            spec.SetContent(intent);

            TabHost.AddTab(spec);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: **An object reference is required for the non-static** field, **method**, or property **'Android.Widget.TabHost.NewTabSpec(string)'**

Answer (score 0):

As Selvin pointed out, you should get a reference to your TabHost and then call its (instance) method NewTabSpec, like:

```
TabHost th = FindViewById<TabHost>(Resource.Id.myTabHost);
var spec = th.NewTabSpec(tag);
```

Comment: First line I'd put in OnCreate and then pass it to CreateTab as an argument.